# Trigger.io + Angular.js and updating a view after calling forge.ajax

Tags: asynchronous, angularjs, trigger.io

Having a problem, and so far couldn't get any solutions for seemingly similar SO questions to work. Problem is this:

Using Trigger.io's forge.ajax, my Angular.js view is not updated after the data is returned. I realize this is because forge.ajax is an asychronous function, and the data is returned after the view has already been displayed. I have tried to update the view by using $rootScope.apply(), but it doesn't work for me as shown in the many examples I have seen.

See the Controller code below:

```
function OfferListCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.offers = [];

   $scope.fetchOffers = function(callback) {

       $scope.offers  = [];

       var successCallback = function(odataResults) {
           var rawJsonData = JSON.parse(odataResults);
           var offers = rawJsonData.d;
           callback(offers);
        };

       var errorCallback = function (error){
            alert("Failure:" + error.message);
       };

       forge.request.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: 'https://www.example.com/ApplicationData.svc/Offers',
           accepts: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
           username: 'username',
           password: 'password',
           success: successCallback,
           error: errorCallback
       });

    };

    $scope.fetchOffers(function(offers) {
        $scope.offers = offers;
        forge.logging.info($scope.offers);
    });
}
```

All the code there works fine, and $scope.offers gets populated with the Offer data from the database. The logging function shows the data is correct, and in the correct format.

I have tried using $rootScope.apply() in the logical places (and some illogical ones), but cannot get the view to update. If you have any ideas how I can get this to work, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit: Added HTML**

The HTML is below. Note the button with ng-click="refresh()". This is a just a workaround so I can at least see the data. It calls a one-line refresh function that executes $rootScope.apply(), which does update the view.

```
   <div ng-controller="OfferListCtrl">
        <h1>Offers</h1>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="offer in offers">
            <p>Description: {{offer.Description}}<br />
               Id: {{offer.Id}}<br />
              Created On: {{offer.CreatedOn}}<br />
              Published: {{offer.Published}}<br />
            </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
  <input type="button" ng-click="refresh()" value="Refresh to show data" />
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML in your view look like?

Comment: HTML added above. It's pretty simple, and does update the view when I click the button I added that just calls a function containing only $rootScope.apply().

Comment: Thanks for including the HTML. I just wanted to be sure there weren't any nested scopes tripping you up.  Did you try putting `$scope.$apply()` after `forge.logging.info($scope.offers);`?  That should work.  If it doesn't, then I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Why dont you use the $http AngularJS services to make the request ?

Comment: Mark, I tried that first, since it seemed like the correct place for it. Didn't work.

Comment: Johno, I can't use $http because the webserver does not return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header as required by CORS. This will run on mobile devices using Trigger.io for hardware interaction (camera, etc), and they provide forge.ajax as a way around this problem. Angular has $rootScope.apply()  that seems to be commonly used for this issue (using third-party libraries and then manually synchronizing the view and model. Only I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
$scope.fetchOffers(function(offers) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.offers = offers;
    });
    forge.logging.info($scope.offers);
});
```

It is because all changes to the `$scope` has to be made within the angular scope, in this case since you are calling ajax request using `forge` the callback is not executing within the angular framework, that is why it is not working.

You can use [$scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) in this case to execute the code within angular framework.

Look at the `$apply()` methods doc

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life-cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Comment: I was sure I tried this, but apparently not, because it works. I had found another solution that worked, but it didn't feel like "the angular way", and this does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
function MyController($scope, myService) 
{
    myService.fetchOffers(data){
        //assign your data here something like below or whateever
        $offers = data 
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Thanks
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

> When I do that I have an error like : "$digest already in progress"...
>   I'm Working with $q...
>
> Someone knwo how I can resolve this issue ?

yes, this is caused where ur data comes fast enough and angular has not finished his rendering so the update cant update "outside" angular yet.

so use events:
http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/angularjs-and-ajax-angular-is-not.html